# connect-flash message with HTML?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, connect-flash

I would like to include a link in the text of a connect-flash message:

**JS**

```
req.flash("registerMessage", "Sorry, the User ID you chose is already in use. Please choose another. If you have already registered and need assistance logging in, <a href=\"http://www.example.com/support/\">contact support</a>");
```

**EJS**

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>
```

**Result**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, the User ID you chose is already in use. Please choose another. If you have already registered and need assistance logging in, &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.example.com/support/&quot;&gt;contact support&lt;/a&gt;.</div>
```

Is there a way to prevent flash from escaping the HTML characters so I can display links in my messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use :

```
<%- message %>
```

to output unescaped HTML

Comment: If `message` contained input from the user should it be treated as unsafe?